# How to implement In-App purchase with dynamic price without using third party SDK in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I want to activate an In-App purchase in my app, such that if we enter a value it should be multiplied by the Tier value we selected (example: $.99) in iTunes Connect and show the actual amount as the payable amount in the alert and also it should be deducted from the account.

If this is not possible with IAP, Then which SDK allows this functionality?

Comment: You means localized price in different store?

Comment: No,i have product with $1, multiple purchase functionality is there, so how can i handle the situation.I read some comments like IAP only allows on a fixed price purchases.